# Handle unknown URL routes in Angular and passing it to an valid route if you URL contains some valid text

Tags: angular, routes, redirect, angular-routing, angular-router

In Angular 6+, I want to handle a unknown URLs that is not defined in the angular application routing. lets say I enter a URL as 'http://10.10.1.33:8080/MyApp/this/url/is/not/defined/alerts' and this kind of URL isn't defined anywhere in the app and I want to check is the last part of the URL contains a 'alerts' part and want to redirect it to 'http://10.10.1.33:8080/MyApp/MyAlerts' with all the other url params.

Assume there are multiple redirection depending on the last part of the URL like

- 'http://10.10.1.33:8080/MyApp/this/url/is/not/defined/users' redirects
  'http://10.10.1.33:8080/MyApp/Users'
- 'http://10.10.1.33:8080/MyApp/this/url/is/not/defined/products' redirects
  'http://10.10.1.33:8080/MyApp/products'
- 'http://10.10.1.33:8080/MyApp/this/url/is/not/defined/' redirects
  'http://10.10.1.33:8080/MyApp/' - redirected to root since there is no valid text in URL like products and users at the end

basically I want a handler who checks the invalid URLs (path: "**") and redirects them into different valid routes defined. but if the URL does not have any kind of valid text i want to just redirect it to the root of the app.

Comment: You need to create route Guard that if doesnt recognize route path parts will redirect for example check https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad

Comment: Have a look at https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-smart-404-page-85a45b109fd8 and just modify the logic.